# Why can't Apache "determine my server's qualified name?"

Tags: apache

I created a new virtual host for my Django application in Apache in my "sites-available" folder:

```
NameVirtualHost 74.181.105.228:80
<VirtualHost 74.181.105.228:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com

# Run the SLMCS Django application.
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/david/djangosites/mydomain/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptReloading On

Alias /static/ /home/david/staticFiles/

<Directory /home/david/djangosites/mydomain>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

</Virtualhost>
```

After I restart Apache with "sudo apachectl restart", the site http://mydomain.com works fine. However, Apache outputs this warning.

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using 74.181.105.228 for ServerName
```

What does this mean? I specified the ServerName directive in my Virtualhost, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server doesn't have a `ServerName`. You set one, but only for your VirtualHost, not for the server itself.

Comment: Thank you, what is the purpose though of setting a ServerName for a server if a virtual host is an abstraction for a website hosted (not the server itself?). In other words, no one is going to visit the server, right? Clients are visiting individual websites.

Comment: The server itself always provides a website too, even if nobody access it (Thats usually this static "It works!"-site ;)). Additional thats just a warning (or even a notice? Don't know exactly right now), thus you can even ignore it and keep it as it is.